# Proper custom PDF bookmarks with changed page numeration

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, page-numbering, bookmarks, roman-numerals

I have following code in which I use custom heading to:

1. Create TOC entry
2. Create custom bookmark

And I want first PDF bookmark to point to `TOC` page.

Since `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}` automatically creates PDF bookmarks if either `hyperref` or `bookmark` packages are loaded, I used `\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1}` to supress those PDF bookmarks that are created with it. Thanks to it, I can create all bookmarks that I need with `bookmark` package.

```
\documentclass[final,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\def \myheading#1{
\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=-1]{My own bookmark for #1}
}
\begin{document}
\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=-1]{My own TOC bookmark}
\tableofcontents
\myheading{One}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Two}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Three}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Four}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Five}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Code above produces document in which both TOC and PDF bookmarks point to the right places.

However, when I try to change page numbering, things start to go south.

When I use:

```
\documentclass[final,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\def \myheading#1{
\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=-1]{My own bookmark for #1}
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
% \bookmark[page=\thepage,level=-1]{My own TOC bookmark} % This is commented out, because adding it will cause compilation error.
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\myheading{One}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Two}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Three}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Four}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Five}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

TOC works just fine. But PDF bookmarks generated by `bookmarks` package got confused about page numbers of respective headings and they point to wrong place as a result: "Two" bookmark points to page 3 instead of 5, "Three" points to page 7 instead of 9 and so on.

And using bookmark for TOC causes compilation error (so I had to comment it out).

I was able to deal with this particular issue of compilation error by using `\setcounter{page}{1}` instead of `\frontmatter`/`\mainmatter`:

```
\documentclass[final,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\def \myheading#1{
\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=-1]{My own bookmark for #1}
}
\begin{document}
\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=-1]{My own TOC bookmark}
\tableofcontents
\myheading{One}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Two}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Three}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Four}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Five}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

but it makes bookmark for TOC to have same page number (1) as bookmark for "One" and all other PDF bookmarks pointing to wrong page.

How can I create **proper custom bookmarks pointing to right page** (as in first code sample), **while at the same time changing numeration for everything before "One" to roman numerals** (with TOC being on page "i") and **"One" being on page 1**.

(Of course TOC should also point to right pages, but it doesn't seem to be an issue.)

Comment: The page counter has the value `1` twice, since `\frontmatter` etc. changes the pagenumbering

Comment: I suggest to use `dest=...` rather with some uniquely defined hyperref anchor instead of the `page=...` way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `\pdfbookmark` can be used for the table of contents.
- `\texorpdfstring` can be used to get different texts into the table of contents and the bookmarks. Then `pdfbookmarksdepth=-1` is not needed.

Example:

```
\documentclass[final,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\def \myheading#1{%
  \chapter*{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{#1}{My own bookmark for #1}}%
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pdfbookmark[0]{My own TOC bookmark}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\myheading{One}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Two}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Three}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Four}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Five}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you: this solves my problem. Though, I am curious why ``bookmark`` package gets confused by ``\frontmatter``/``\mainmatter`` or any other change in page numeration. You are probably the best person to answer this since you wrote both ``hyperref`` and ``bookmarks`` packages :) (Ps. With your solution, ``bookmarks`` package does not need to be loaded at all, even though you included it in the example).

Comment: @Rafal I would always load package `bookmark`, then the bookmarks get faster updated.

Comment: @Rafal Option `page` expects the *absolute* page number. `\thepage` will only work, if the page number equals the absolute page number and its expansion is a plain number.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proposition using `dest=` instead of `page=` - label usage

```
\documentclass[final,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[depth=-1]{bookmark}

\newcounter{fakecntr}

\newcommand{\myheading}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{fakecntr}
\phantomsection
\chapter*{\hypertarget{chap::\number\value{fakecntr}}{#1}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\bookmark[dest=chap::\number\value{fakecntr},level=-1]{My own bookmark for #1}
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\bookmark[dest=toc::bookmark,level=-1]{My own TOC bookmark}
\hypertarget{toc::bookmark}{\tableofcontents}
\mainmatter
\cleardoublepage
\myheading{One}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Two}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Three}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Four}
\blindtext[10]
\myheading{Five}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```